# In plotly is there a way to create a second yAxis that is simply a scaled version of the first yAxis?

Tags: graph, dataset, plotly, axis, yaxis

I'm creating a graph in plotly, and what I want to do is fairly simple.

I have a scatter-plot with temperature values. On the left side, I want a y-axis with Celsius, and on the right side I want to scale the values to Fahrenheit (9/5c + 32).

I realize I can duplicate my data, one in Fahrenheit and one in Celsius, but is there a way to simply say y2 = y1 * 9/5 + 32?

From my research, there is no way to do this without having the multiple data sets.  I would appreciate any help I can get here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, I found a workaround to this which suits my use case (though, it would be nice if plotly could do this inherently).

I simply write a function to determine the max y value (out of all the scatter plots) in Celcius and then code that on the Fahrenheit axis (y2).  I make the min=32 and the max 9/5(max_c) + 32.  Then I make the ticks 9/5c.   It causes a little extra work, but it works.